# How to set the max thread a python script could use when calling from shell

Tags: python, multithreading, scikit-learn

Have script a.py, it will run some task with multiple-thread, please noticed that I have no control over the a.py.

I'm looking for a way to limit the number of thread it could use, as I found that using more threads than my CPU core will slow down the script.

It could be something like:

python  --nthread=2 a.py

or Modifying something in my OS is also acceptable .

I am using ubuntu 16.04

As requested:

the a.py is just a module in scikit-learn the [MLPRegressor](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/183722475189b8e21ee2e621b19acca3c9e054d8/sklearn/neural_network/multilayer_perceptron.py) .
I also asked this question [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/7280).

Comment: How do you make the multi-threaded python script? Snippets of codes will help.

Comment: Your idea of limiting the number of threads to increase performance is naive: such fine tuning might help in some specific situations if you were actually programming `a.py`, but there are situations where more threads would be faster and where just one thread is best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A more general way, not specific to python:

```
taskset -c 1-3 python yourProgram.py
```

In this case the threads 1-3 (3 in total) will be used. Any parallelization invoked by your program will share those resources.

For a solution that fits your exact problem you should better identify which part of the code parellelizes. For instance, if it is due to numpy routines, you could limit it by using:

```
OMP_NUM_THREADS=4 python yourProgram.py
```

Again, the first solution is general and handled by the os, whereas the second is python (numpy) specific.

Answer (score 0):

Read the [threading](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html) doc, it said:

> CPython implementation detail: In CPython, due to the Global Interpreter Lock, only one thread can execute Python code at once (even though certain performance-oriented libraries might overcome this limitation). If you want your application to make better use of the computational resources of multi-core machines, you are advised to use multiprocessing. However, threading is still an appropriate model if you want to run multiple I/O-bound tasks simultaneously.

If you will like to take advantage of the multi-core processing better update the code to use [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) module.

In case that you prefer anyway continue using threading, you have one option passing the number of threads to the application as an argument like:

```
python a.py --nthread=2
```

Then you can update the script code to limit the threads.